# Why does JavaScript lack commands to import subfiles?

Tags: javascript, file, include

Most programming/markup languages that I know have commands called `include`, `import`, `load`, `require`, `input`, etc. that call subfiles from the main file, but as far as I know, JavaScript does not have such feature, and a suggestion that I often see for such case is to insert a `<script>` tag into the dom (programmatically from the main file), which I think is very indirect. Why does JavaScript lack such feature? Was there any design decision?

Comment: It runs on client side and load and run the scripts thats all. :)

Comment: There are solutions here: [browserify](http://browserify.org/), [requirejs](http://www.requirejs.org/), [enderjs](http://ender.jit.su/).

Comment: Some guys from netscape still around ? Essentially problem is javascript is not compiled - it is scripting language. And twenty years after it was created, we still torture hardware with reading, parsing and writing html and compiling javascript on the fly. Personally I wouldn't be against if some compilable technology (java applet/flash/silverlight) would emerge as winner, but that is not going to happen.

Answer (score 1):

who said no? Read about this tool: [Helios Kernel](http://home.gna.org/helios/kernel/)
But will it be is conveniently for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you use it with node.js for instance, it does have `require()`.

Unlike most languages, JavaScript is generally client-side. If you want to do this from the client, how would you do that if the file you want to include is actually located on the server? JavaScript does have `eval()` and many other useful functions to do this, but you need to understand that you are dealing with requests through http and not files on a file system.

Comment: Other client side scripts, for example CSS has the ability to call assets like fonts, pictures, etc from the server or anywhere else. So does HTML. But if you are saying that is what is different from other programming language, then it makes sense.